# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes issue not solved by increasing memory limit

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

So i'm getting a 500 internal server error. After looking in the apache2 error log, that's the error I get.

```
[:error] [pid 2248] [client 94.197.122.74:54243] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18 bytes)
```

My code makes multiple requests on large databases (1m+ rows) - so I would imagine that's the problem. I changed my memory usage from 128BM to 500BM in php.ini, unfortunately I'm getting the same error...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't load large volumes of data from a database to arrays, if you can help it

Comment: change LONGTEXTS to TEXT as well if you have any in your mysql database. I had the same issue and solved it by changing LONGTEXTS to TEXT.

Comment: Doesn't this error also give you a file and line number?

Comment: Problem with this error is it can occur on a line that isn't really the major problem. For example you load 500mb of data from a database into an array (using up a massive amount of memory) but then you get the problem shortly afterwards when moving a small amount around. If it is database related then try to move some of the processing to the database so you only return a smaller amount of data.

Comment: You still have a 128MB limit after changing it to 500MB? Or your're now hitting the 500MB limit?

Answer (score 0):

change `LONGTEXTS` to `TEXT` as well if you have any in your mysql database. I had the same issue and solved it by changing `LONGTEXTS` to `TEXT`.

YOU CAN SIMPLY DO THIS FROM WITHIN YOUR `PHPMYADMIN` IF YOU HAVE ACCESS TO ONE.

Furthermore, use `VARCHAR` if/where possible.

use `TEXT` instead of `LONG TEXT`.

Do not pull a hue amount of data from database at once.

customize your PHP and `query execution` in your PHP files.